# How to Deal With Changing Elements In XPath?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

My Code is:

`bar = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ember26']/input")`

But it changes every time I login. I can login with my codes but inside the LinkedIn, search bar XPath changes, like ;

//*[@id='ember16']/input or something else.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I tried to find, for example, by class name but it was useless again as well as by css selector.

Comment: You've run into the issue of dynamic IDs, so they'll always change the xpath or CSS selector if you base your element on IDs. Are you testing LinkedIn website? Is this for learning practice? If you don't have control of the website, then you can't change the behavior.

Comment: I am a beginner in Python. But i do what my instructor does. He can get the xpaths easily.

Comment: Please add the html.you are trying to inspect

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/feed/

Answer (score 2):

**xpath:**

```
//*[contains(@id,"ember")]/input
```

or

```
//*[starts-with(@id,"ember")]/input
```

**css**

```
[id*="ember"]>input
```

or

```
[id^="ember"]>input
```

- is css for contains and ^ start with for css

you can use any of the above locator to find the search field in linkedin

Comment: Can you explain the difference between //* and // ?

Comment: // any where in the preceding node context , eg //div looks div any where under div (not only direct child)    /div//span this searches for span tag any where under the /div tag .  *  means any. //*/div means  div tag which is child of any tag , it can be span , div anything

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Please accept  the answer by clikcing the tick sign if it helped :)

Comment: I cannot accept, only upvote)

Comment: Ho i thought you are the author , thanks for the upvote :)

Comment: Generally, for dynamic IDs this won't be a solution where multiple objects exist with these common values as suffix/prefix.

Comment: I tried these but it turned out that out of several trials, it worked out just one time and i used `//*[starts-with(@id,"ember")]/input`  . What else i can do ?

Comment: try wait explicit waits

Answer (score 0):

You can use partial matches with css selectors.  So where you have id=ember26 above, in that case, you could use:

`css=input[id^='ember']`    (the ^ means starts with)

You can also use endswidth, and contains.

[A great write up I found on all the different ways of handling dynamic cases](https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/css-selector-selenium-webdriver-tutorial/) will hopefully help.

Comment: I tried plenty of methods like start with and contains. They did not help out. I dont know whether the problem is i cant use them or not.

Comment: @KadirÖzdemir note that you'll need to use css selectors, not xpath...

Comment: I havent used them so i am disoriented a bit.